# Google Adsense says "low value content “ for ReactJS website with dynamic page content

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, adsense, google-ads-script, adsense-anchor-ads

My website which is a reactJS-based SPA, hosted on GitHub Pages with a custom domain.

All the routes go to various backends and then generate the page content, without backend response, most of the pages would be blank.

When I requested Google AdSense on my website to show ads at the bottom, I get the error that "**the site has low-value content**".

I found this link in one of the questions on stack overflow
[React SEO Problems](https://rubygarage.org/blog/seo-for-react-websites)

I am using GitHub pages and have dynamic content served from AWS Lambda and google and FacebookDev APIs, so I can not use SSR/Preloading

what is the best way to fix it, without rewriting a lot of code?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/125202531/low-value-content-need-explanation?hl=en), It's common to have problems getting approved on Google Adsense, even when you think that your site has got enough higher-value content.

Quoted from that link:

> Low-value content means your content is not valuable in the eyes of Google and its viewers. Google always wants to provide quality content with real value to its users so, the content in your website must be qualitative.

> When you got this kind of message from Adsense; 'Low quality content issues' Adsense found that there isn't sufficient, original and rich content that would be of value to users.

Having low traffic to your site is also a known to cause rejects by Google Adsense, so if you're site has only been online for a few days, that could also be a reason your site has been rejected.